# ant design onSelect is not firing

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, components, antd, uicomponents

I'm trying to use [Autocomplete](https://ant.design/components/auto-complete/) from Ant Design, but the "onSelect" is not firing. Everything else is working well - when I type into the search bar, my ingredient list appears and filters as intended. If I console log "data" in onChange, the search's values appears (the "data"). When I click on an item from my filtered pop up menu, the menu disappears, the value in the input remains the same as before (i.e. it does not change to the selected item) and nothing is fired to the console. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Added a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-worker-0o7h1?file=/src/pages/index.tsx).

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
export default function Searchbar() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  const [options, setOptions] = useState<{ value: string }[]>([]);

  const ingredients = useSelector(state => state.ingredients);

  const onSearch = (searchTerm: string) => {
    setOptions(
      !searchTerm ? [] : ingredients.filter(ferment =>
        ferment.label.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())
      ))
    };

    const onSelect = (data: string) => {
      console.log("onSelect", data);

    };

    const onChange = (data: string) => {
      setValue(data);
      console.log(data)
    };
     
    return (
      <>

    <AutoComplete
        options={options}
        value={value}
        style={{ width: 200 }}
        onSelect={onSelect}
        onSearch={onSearch}
        onChange={onChange}
        placeholder="looking for"
      />
       
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: This appears to be correct from what I can tell. Can you try reproducing this in a *running* codesandbox and link it here in your question?

Comment: Just added a sandbox. thanks!

Comment: I am unable to run your codesandbox. Can you try a simpler one that isolates your `Searchbar` component and behavior?

Answer (score 2):

`<AutoComplete />` expects prop `options` with items that must have `value` prop.

You pass `ingredients` as `options` to `AutoComplete` and ingredients don't have this property.

This is the reason why the callback `onSelect` is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

When creating search options we need to specify `value key :pair` for example `value: item?.title,`for onSelect to understand which one was selected.